# Stream Parsing of Turtle syntax with jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

I have a problem and even after hours of search I could not find a suitable solution. I want to parse a huge RDF document in turtle syntax (~8GB). This is why I chose a stream approach offered by jena riot, namely the [RDFDataMgr](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html).
The file I am processing uses invalid URIs, which contain whitespaces. This raises a fatal exception and the parsing stops. I would like to recognize those
invalid URI beforhand and skip the whole statement, as it is of no use anyways. I have tried the proposed solution from the [apache email archive](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201605.mbox/%3C573AD96C.2080202@apache.org%3E), but as the exception raises before the triple gets emitted, it does not work as expected. Does anyone know where I am mistaken or do I have to find another solution? See here the example code I am using:

```
import org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.Sink;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Triple;
import org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDF;
import org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFLib;
import org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFWrapper;
import org.apache.jena.riot.system.SyntaxLabels;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.core.Quad;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;
import org.apache.jena.riot.out.SinkQuadOutput;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class JenaStreamWrapper extends StreamRDFWrapper {

    public static void main(String... argv) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filename = "file.ttl";
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.nq"));
        StreamRDF filtered = new JenaStreamWrapper(StreamRDFLib.writer(outputStream));
        RDFDataMgr.parse(filtered, filename);
    }

    public JenaStreamWrapper(StreamRDF other) {
        super(other);
    }

    @Override
    public void triple(Triple triple) {
        if ((triple.getSubject().isURI() && triple.getSubject().getURI().contains(" "))
                || (triple.getObject().isURI() && triple.getObject().getURI().contains(" ")))
            System.out.println(triple.getSubject().getURI());
        else
            other.triple(triple);
    }
}
```

And here some example statements extracted from the dataset:

```
@prefix gndo: <http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix dnbt: <http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/dnb/> .

<http://d-nb.info/gnd/117177040> a gndo:DifferentiatedPerson ;
        owl:sameAs <http://viaf.org/viaf/64153583> ;
        gndo:gndIdentifier "117177040" ;
        gndo:oldAuthorityNumber "(DE-588a)117177040" , "(DE-588a)117177040670 BnF" ;
        owl:sameAs <http://d-nb.info/gnd/117177040670 BnF> ;
        dnbt:deprecatedUri "http://d-nb.info/gnd/117177040670 BnF" ;
        gndo:oldAuthorityNumber "(DE-588)117177040670 BnF" ;
        gndo:variantNameForThePerson "Jourdan, Camille" ;
        gndo:variantNameEntityForThePerson _:node1aj1cbug9x62759112 .
```

When executing the code I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 9, col: 55] Bad character in IRI (space): <http://d-nb.info/gnd/117177040670[space]...>
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:165)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:108)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectItem(LangTurtleBase.java:286)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectList(LangTurtleBase.java:280)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triples(LangTurtleBase.java:249)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesSameSubject(LangTurtleBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.oneTopLevelElement(LangTurtle.java:46)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:179)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:861)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:667)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:637)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:626)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:617)
    at zbw.tbl.schemex.additions.JenaStreamWrapper.main(JenaStreamWrapper.java:27)
```

I am thankful for anykind of useful input.

Comment: As the error message says: your IRI contains a space which is a disallowed character.

`<http://d-nb.info/gnd/117177040670 BnF>` should be `<http://d-nb.info/gnd/117177040670%20BnF>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was aware of that (see 4th sentence of my question). However, checking all errors before parsing is not possible in a general use case...

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue but was getting only warnings and not fatal exceptions. My Jena version is 3.2.0. To stop those warnings I had to tweak the Jena code a little. I overwrote the `org.apache.jena.riot.tokens.TokenizerText` class and changed the value of private static variable `AllowSpacesInIRI` from `false` to `true`

Comment: Please write keywords like `private static` in code style. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this helps a lot and makes your questions and answers more readable.